# Using turbostreams in wicked wizard's "show" action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, wicked-gem

I'm confused about the pattern someone would use to replace an item in the dom using turbo streams in combination with wicked wizard using the "show action". In my scenario, I'm trying to replace a nested turboframe "foo" that exists on step_b using the "show" action, which looks like this:

```
def show 
  case step

  when :step_a

  when :step_b
 
  when :step_c

  render_wizard
end
```

In step_b's view, I have several links, and they all link back to step b, but with different params. (I'm actually using an API call to fetch and render times in an appointment picker, and the params represent the dates for those times).

`<%= link_to "Today", step_b_path(date: 03-14-23) %>`

Would ideally replace the "foo" turboframe inside step_b's view with all the times for 3/14/23.

`<%= link_to "Tomorrow", step_b_path(date: 03-15-23) %>`

Would ideally replace the "foo" turboframe inside step_b's view with all the times for 3/15/23.

The user can keep clicking these links, which will update the appointment times, until they finally pick and submit their appointment selection for that step in the form. Once they select a time and click "submit" it calls the `update` action and proceeds to step_c

I've seen that if I have a `<%= turbo_frame_tag "foo" %>` on step_a, I can create a `step_b.turbo_stream.erb` to replace the turboframe on step a by doing something like this:

`<%= turbo_stream.replace "foo", partial: "partial_path", locals: { bar: @baz } %>`

However, I'm having issues with this because it seems like this only gets called when a user "submits" and calls the update function. What I want is for the turboframe to update when they click on a link to step_b, which only calls the "show" action. The nested turbo frame I'm trying to update only exists on step_b.

However, when I try to add something like this to the `show` action:

```
when :step_b
  respond_to do |format|
    format.turbo_stream { render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.replace("foo", partial: "partial_path", locals: {bar: params[:baz] 
  })}
end
```

it causes a double render conflict with `render_wizard`. I've tried doing an if/else statement like this:

```
if step == :times
  respond_to do |format|
    format.turbo_stream { render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.replace("foo", partial: "partial_path", locals: {bar: params[:baz] } )}
    format.html { times_path }
  end
else
    render_wizard
end
```

Which doesn't render the step at all. I haven't been able to find much information that connects wicked and turbostreams. I have many more steps other than just `step_b` that also use the `render_wizard` method, and was wondering if there's a way to accomplish this without a massive refactor?

per the docs I've seen (linked below), it states "You'll need to call render_wizard at the end of your action to get the correct views to show up." and if the turbo_stream view conflicts with render_wizard, it sounds like this might not be possible.

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/wicked/1.3.4

all the examples I've seen using turbostream just tend to assume you have a very typical rails scaffold setup, where the "create" action maps to the `create.turbo_stream.erb` and the "delete" action maps to the `delete.turbo_stream.erb`, so it's hard to figure out exactly how to implement the same solutions if the controller looks different than those, as they do when using wicked wizard

---

### EDIT:

See the comment below from Alex who was able to provide me with an answer for my issue. I just wanted to post a quick summary:

Somewhere in my step_b view, I have something similar to this -

**step_b.html.erb:**

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "foo_frame" do %>
  <%= some_variable %>
<%= end %>

<%= link_to "step b", step_b_path(some_variable: "new value of some_variable"), data: { "turbo_stream": true } %>
```

As seen above, in the view for step_b you'll need a link with `data-turbo-stream=true`. This will cause the link click to be of type "text/vnd.turbo-stream.html", which is a typical turbo-stream request. Then when we later do `respond_to do |format|` that will tell rails to execute the `format.turbo_stream` code in your steps controller.

**steps_controller.rb**

```
def show
    respond_to do |format|
      case step
      when :step_a
        # dostuff
        
      when :step_b
        if request.referrer.include? wizard_url
          format.turbo_stream { render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update("foo_frame", partial: path_to_partial, locals: { some_variable: params[:some_variable] }) }
        end
        
      when :step_c
        # dostuff
      
      format.html { render_wizard }
    end
end
```

For the issue I was running into, it seems that when navigating from step_a to step_b it's trying to process it as a turbostream and doesn't render the view for step_b. It may be because I have a nested turbostream in my case. However, I wanted to be able to target and replace a specific, nested turbostream.

The line `if request.referrer.include? wizard_url` basically just says "If the request is coming from the same step_b page, then perform this turbostream update on the "foo" turboframe. Therefore this code won't execute when transitioning from step_a to step_b, which resolves the issue described above

Thanks to Alex for all of his help, and providing a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really feel like *wicked* just makes it a lot more confusing for you. You can just as easily use turbo frame with your existing controllers with whatever actions and responses you like.

Here is what I've come up with *wicked* and some commented out regular controller alternatives:

```rb
class OnboardingController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard

  steps :one, :two, :complete
  # # or you can do it on your own
  # STEPS = ["one", "two", "complete"].freeze

  # GET wizard_path
  def show
    # NOTE: if you want to add turbo_stream responses here, respond_to
    #       block needs to wrap around the case statement, so that
    #       render_wizard can be wrapped as well.
    respond_to do |format|
      # case params[:id].to_sym
      case step
      when :one
        # NOTE: it's better to have a default value when params[:date] is empty
        #       on initial request.
        #       add links in step :one template with different date params
        #       when you click them, just let the page render again, there is
        #       no need to do anything else.
        @user = current_user
        format.turbo_stream { render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update("stream_target", "step one content") }
      end
      format.html { render_wizard }
    end

    # # if you just replace `render_wizard` with you own simple logic, you
    # # won't need wicked wizard and won't have to fight it
    # respond_to do |format|
    #   format.html { render params[:id].presence_in(STEPS) || STEPS.first }
    # end
  end

  # PUT wizard_path
  def update
    case step
    when :one
      @user = current_user
      skip_step if @user.save
    end
    render_wizard
    # # or let render_wizard save it for you and go to the next step
    # render_wizard @user

    # # or do it yourself and turn it into a regular controller
    # respond_to do |format|
    #   if @user.save
    #     next_step = STEPS[STEPS.index(params[:id]).next]
    #     format.html { render next_step }
    #   else
    #     format.html { render params[:id] }
    #   end
    # end
  end

  # # and make your own helpers
  # private
  # def step
  #   params[:id].to_sym
  # end
  # helper_method :step
end
```

You can add a partial layout, so you don't have to repeat things between steps:

```rb
# app/views/onboarding/_wizard_layout.html.erb

<%# NOTE: if you want the url to update as well     vvvvvvv %>
<%= turbo_frame_tag "wizard", data: {turbo_action: :advance} do %>
  <div class="flex items-center mb-4 gap-4">
    <%= link_to "< back", previous_wizard_path, class: "hover:text-blue-500" %>
    <h1 class="text-2xl font-bold">Step <%= step %></h1>
  </div>
  <%= yield %>
<% end %>
```

```rb
# app/views/onboarding/one.html.erb

<%= render layout: "wizard_layout" do %>
  <%= turbo_frame_tag "time_selector" do %>

    <%= tag.div class: "flex gap-4" do %>
      <% date = Date.parse(params[:date] || Date.today.to_s) %>
      <%# NOTE: link to the current step with different params.
        #       you have to pass `params[:id]` so you don't override the current
        #       step name. %>
      <%= link_to "prev day", wizard_path(params[:id], {date: date.prev_day}), class: "text-blue-500" %>
      <%= link_to "today",    wizard_path(params[:id], {date: Date.today}),    class: "text-blue-500" %>
      <%= link_to "next day", wizard_path(params[:id], {date: date.next_day}), class: "text-blue-500" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= params[:date] %>

    <%# NOTE: just an example of how stream response would work
      #       because it is in a `show` action, it has to be a GET
      #       request. to make a GET turbo stream request you have to
      #       set `data-turbo-stream="true"` attribute %>
    <%= tag.div id: "stream_target" %>
    <%= button_to "a stream action", wizard_path, method: :get, data: {turbo_stream: true}, class: "bg-gray-100 px-2 py-1" %>

    <%# NOTE: put your form here, use outer frame as the target
      #       otherwise, you'll be stuck in a `time_selector` frame %>
    <%= form_with model: @user, url: wizard_path, method: :put, data: {turbo_frame: :wizard} do |f| %>
      <%= f.submit "Next button", class: "font-bold"  %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

#### Update

`<button>` submits the form that it is nested in, that's just html. `button_to` is a *rails* helper that makes a form with a button to make *POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE* requests, use it outside of forms.

The issue is that everything is smooshed together in one action. When you submit the form it sends a *TURBO_STREAM* request, when you redirect *turbo* sends another *TURBO_STREAM* request to redirected url (which is `show` action). If you have `format.turbo_stream` that's the response you will get, otherwise, `format.html` is used.

I mean, just another reason to ditch the wizard, or at least add some new actions for `turbo_stream` requests. But you can work around it:

```rb
def update
  # ...

  # NOTE: redirect with .html extension so that `show` response
  #       would be html instead of turbo_stream
  render_wizard @user, {}, format: :html
end
```

or

```rb
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    case step
    when :one
      @user = current_user
      format.turbo_stream { render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update("stream_target", "step one content") }
    when :two
      # NOTE: only accept turbo_stream requests from the current
      #       step. that means when you redirect there is no
      #       turbo_stream format and html format will be used instead
      if request.referrer == wizard_url
        format.turbo_stream { render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update("stream_target", "step two content") }
      end
    end
    format.html { render_wizard }
  end
end
```

This might help explain this further: *https://stackoverflow.com/a/75657122/207090*

Comment: Thank you for your response. You've been incredibly patient & helpful and I greatly appreciate that. Would it be at all possible to get this example without the appointments model? I feel like that adds an extra layer of complexity that's a little distracting to the issue I'm running into. I made a git repo that implements something similar to your OnboardingController and the readme describes what I'm running into. Also when I change the link_to to button_to, it seems to submit the form rather than make a get request: https://github.com/APysnack/wicked-wizard-sandbox

Comment: @APysnack see update. maybe just add some new actions to handle side requests that are unrelated to actual wizard navigation. it's just hard to put all the steps and different request formats into one action.